# Problem with loading font metrics file

Tags: texlive, linux, font-metrics

Trying to make PDF output with pdflatex halts with this message:

`Font T1/ptm/m/n/10=ptmr8t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found`

After searching a bit I found that file `ptmr8t.tfm` is already present on my system and located as `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr8t.fmt`

What could be the problem?

---

Update: command `kpsewhich ptmr8t.tfm` outputs:

`/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr8t.tfm`

but from the previous log file, seems like `mktextfm ptmr8t` command was called prior halting

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What does the shell command `kpsewhich ptmr8t.tfm` answer?

Comment: It may be a permission problem. Probably opening a chat room is the best thing to do, as these problems require doing many tests.

Comment: I was able to overcome this problem on another PC, but then there are other errors. IMHO, it's just too common for projects that depend on Sphinx automation, latex output to be w/o issue. I guess I should stick to HTML output, being noob at TeX. Maybe someone should close this question. Thanks for you help, and cheers